# Error while adding Google Maps Activity in navigation drawer (material Design)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am Using Google maps activity in my android application which Implements Material Design, When I am trying to add the Google maps activity in Navigation 't Drawer the application shows an error "Incompatible Types - Required : android.support.v4.app.Fragment". 
Here is my mainactivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import info.androidhive.materialdesign.R;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {
    private WebView myWebView;
    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();


    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);




        // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
        displayView(0);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if(id == R.id.action_search){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search action is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        displayView(position);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_home);
                break;

            case 1:
                fragment = new FriendsFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_friends);
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new MessagesFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_messages);
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new ContactFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_contact);
                break;
            case 4:
               fragment=new HospitalMapsActivity();
                title = "Detect Hospital";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            // set the toolbar title
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen your concrete implementatios, but I think that one (or all) of this classes are `android.app.Fragment` instead of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`: `HomeFragment`, `FriendsFragment`, `MessagesFragment` or `ContactFragment`.

To solve your problem, your fragments must `extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment`